# ¿Cómo compartir variables entre diferentes scripts?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo crear una variable global accesible desde cualquier script de la aplicación web, sin usar el almacenamiento local ni los cookies? Según tengo entendido, anteriormente se usaba el objeto windows como objeto global para acceder a cualquier variable declarada globalmente, pero por razones de seguridad, lo han anulado en la nueva versión de js.

```
<body>
   //Un script
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var globalTest = "varible global";
   </script>

   //Otro script
   <script type="text/javascript">
      console.log(window.globalTest); //Undefined
   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Si ambos scripts residen en el mismo DOM entonces no hay ningún problema, de lo contrario sí.

Answer (score 2):

Si ambos scripts pertenecen al mismo *DOM* entonces no hay ningun problema, y todas las variables declaradas en el ámbito global se almacenan en *window*.

```
[eduen@EDUENPC ~]$ cat prueba.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Prueba de ámbitos </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script>
        var variableGlobal = "Esta es una variable global"
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var t = document.createTextNode(variableGlobal)
    var h = document.createElement('h1')
    h.appendChild(t)
    if(variableGlobal === window.variableGlobal)
      {
        document.body.appendChild(h)
      }
</script>
</body>
</html>
[eduen@EDUENPC ~]$ firefox --new-tab file:///home/eduen/prueba.html
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues a mi no me la reconoce, como escribí al principio en el código, me dice "undefined".

Comment: ¿Qué navegador estás utilizando?